# Change alpha component on navigationBar barTintColor

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I need to change the alpha component of barTintColor of the navigationController's navigationBar. The alpha value must increase when the user scroll down a scrollview add in the view controller.
I'm trying to set a UIColor with a alpha component less than 1.0, but the navigation bar set this color always with an alpha equal to 1.0, there are some tricks i could use to change the alpha of the navigationBar programmatically?

Comment: Hey check [LTNavigationbar](https://github.com/ltebean/LTNavigationbar) which might be helpful.

Comment: this is a good solution, but when i change the color, then i can't tap in the back button

Comment: [BLKFlexibleHeightBar](https://github.com/bryankeller/BLKFlexibleHeightBar/) lets you customize a header bar any way you want. You can make something like Facebook's header, Safari's header, Square Cash's header, or anything else you can think of. It can look the same *and* behave the same. Check it out if you want a ton of customization options.